# Is gsutil rsync able for app with permission only for upload files? (ResumableUploadAbortException: does not have storage.objects.delete access)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, rsync, gsutil

I have used `gsutil rsync` without `-d` argument, even without any argument, but I still got `ResumableUploadAbortException: 403 abc@xyz.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.delete access`.

I want to create an application only for upload files to google cloud storage, using `gsutil rsync` from google compute engine.

I have added permission to read and list,
because I don't want the application able to delete any of file in the bucket, so I did not give permission for `storage.objects.delete`.

Is there any parameter to use the `gsutil rsync` command without having to give access to delete a file? 
I want to use `rsync` because I have to transfer gigabytes of files.

thank you.

**[EDIT]** add additional information and debug:

I want to add additional information,
this app running as cron, upload timestamp generated filename, so it would be different everytime it executed.

The upload process actually worked, the file uploaded to the bucket, but I still got `ResumableUploadAbortException` at the end.

so I run `gsutil -D rsync` to debug:

```
DEBUG: Exception stack trace:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/__main__.py", line 590, in _RunNamedCommandAndHandleExceptions
        user_project=user_project)
      File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command_runner.py", line 372, in RunNamedCommand
        return_code = command_inst.RunCommand()
      File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/commands/rsync.py", line 1546, in RunCommand
        fail_on_error=True, seek_ahead_iterator=seek_ahead_iterator)
      File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command.py", line 1420, in Apply
        arg_checker, should_return_results, fail_on_error)
      File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command.py", line 1491, in _SequentialApply
        worker_thread.PerformTask(task, self)
      File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command.py", line 2157, in PerformTask
        results = task.func(cls, task.args, thread_state=self.thread_gsutil_api)
      File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/commands/rsync.py", line 1337, in _RsyncFunc
        gzip_exts=cls.gzip_exts, preserve_posix=cls.preserve_posix_attrs)
      File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 3520, in PerformCopy
        allow_splitting=allow_splitting, gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded)
      File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 2026, in _UploadFileToObject
        parallel_composite_upload, logger)
      File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 1877, in _DelegateUploadFileToObject
        elapsed_time, uploaded_object = upload_delegate()
      File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 2015, in CallResumableUpload
        is_component=is_component, gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded_file)
      File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 1687, in _UploadFileToObjectResumable
        progress_callback=progress_callback, gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded)
      File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/cloud_api_delegator.py", line 315, in UploadObjectResumable
        gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded)
      File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_api.py", line 1415, in UploadObjectResumable
        gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded)
      File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_api.py", line 1242, in _UploadObject
        additional_headers, progress_callback, gzip_encoded)
      File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_api.py", line 1371, in _PerformResumableUpload
        raise resumable_ex
    ResumableUploadAbortException: ResumableUploadAbortException: 403 abc@xyz.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.delete access to bucket/filename
```

Comment: Which operation caused that error? If you run gsutil -D rsync ... you should be able to see what gsutil was trying to do when it encountered the error.

Comment: hi @MikeSchwartz,  I have added additional information about the process, also debug information about the DEBUG stack trace. is it enough? or I have to send the POST request? the debug trace in between request `send: PUT /resumable/upload/storage/v1/b/bucket/o` and request `send: 'POST /resumable/upload/storage/v1/b/bucket/o`? thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess, you're trying to overwrite an existing object.  This will delete the existing object, replacing it with another object of the same name.

One alternative might be `gsutil cp -n`, which will not overwrite existing files at the destination.  But if you want to be able to overwrite objects, you'll need delete permission.

#### Edit:

As mentioned in the comments below, this can also happen as the result of parallel composite uploads being enabled (at the point where gsutil attempts to delete the component objects). This behavior can be disabled by setting `parallel_composite_upload_threshold=0` in your boto file, or inline in the command, e.g. `gsutil -o "GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=0"  ...`.

Comment: thank you for the alternative, will try it later. actually, I have tried multiple times, and you are correct if the file exists, then it would needs delete permission to overwrite. but in this case, my app running periodically on a scheduler (cron), the filename generated uniquely from the timestamp, and the local file deleted after transfer to the bucket. but I still get the ResumableUploadAbortException.

Comment: I wonder if the files you're uploading are large enough to trigger parallel composite uploads -- this would result in gsutil uploading the file as several parts, composing them into one object, and then trying to delete objects representing the parts.  Try setting `parallel_composite_upload_threshold = 0`, either in your .boto config file or inline in the command, e.g. `gsutil -o "GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=0" rsync ...`

Comment: on debugging message, after show "Copying file ..." there's a note `You are uploading one or more large file(s), which would run
significantly faster if you enable parallel composite uploads. This
feature can be enabled by editing the
"parallel_composite_upload_threshold" value in your .boto
configuration file.`, is that what you mean? So I don't think that the composite upload is active.
I will try to disable with inline command and will be back to report the result tomorrow. thank you.

Comment: That message indiciates parallel composite uploads are disabled, so the second idea mhouglum@ suggested isn't the root cause of your permission problem. Can you tell us what API operation was being attempted (from further down in the debug log) when the permission failure happened?

Comment: here's the sequence:

1. `INFO base_api.py] Calling method storage.objects.insert with StorageObjectsInsertRequest`

2. `INFO base_api.py] Making http POST to https://www.googleapis.com/resumable/upload/storage/..`

3. `send: PUT /resumable/upload/storage/v1/b/bucket/o?..`

4. then here is the ResumableUploadAbortException stack trace

5. `send: 'POST /resumable/upload/storage/v1/b/bucket/o?`

Comment: before the stack trace, I think this is like a progress of upload? 
-
- [0 files][ 94.4 MiB/288.0 MiB]                                                
\
|
| [0 files][207.8 MiB/288.0 MiB]                                                
/

Comment: The API operation that was attempted when you got the permission error was trying to write to an object, which does sound like the original diagnosis mhouglum@ suggested (trying to overwrite an existing object). Are you sure the object it's trying to upload is a new path and not attempting to overwrite an existing object?

Comment: currently set inline command with `gsutil -o "GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=0" rsync ...` solve my problem, I did not get any `ResumableUploadAbortException` again.
thank you @MikeSchwartz and @mhouglum